# how to do a date formula in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to do a query that automatically increments the date year by year. For example, I use this formula:

```
=INDEX(query('Scheda Intervento'!C3:K14;"select sum (K) where (F >= date '2013-01-01' and F <= date '2013-01-31' and C = '" & A3 &"')");2;1)
```

... but every year I have to change the date everywhere that it appears in the formula (in 2014, 2015) etc.

A copy of my spreadsheet is shared [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtZwzv4EAc54dGRkcnlOS2JoMjZJQjktOGR4aENUX0E#gid=5). This formula is in the sheet "riepilogo totale ore , date, compensi operatore" in cell C2.

How do I get my formulas to update automatically in future years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expressed the months as dates in the header of your "riepilogo" (summary) sheet, you could reference them in your formula. By starting the row with a year number, you can easily have the dates adjust to changes in year.

For example, here A2 is the year, expressed as a simple number. B2, for Gennaio (January), builds the date using the `Date(year,month,day)` spreadsheet function, in this case 2013/1/1. The following months use the `EDATE(date,number_of_months)` spreadsheet function to set the first day of each subsequent month.

[image: Date calculations]

Now, adjust your formula to reference the date for the month. The `date` operator expects dates in the form "yyyy-mm-dd", so you need to use the `TEXT` function to format them. Here's what the formula in B3 will look like:

```
=INDEX(query('Scheda Intervento'!$C$2:$K$13;ʺselect sum (K) where (F >= date'ʺ & text(B$2,ʺyyyy-mm-ddʺ) & ʺ' and F < date 'ʺ & text(edate(B$2,1),ʺyyyy-mm-ddʺ) & ʺ' and C = 'ʺ & $A3 &ʺ')ʺ);2;1)
```

Note that `EDATE()` is used again - this is so that the formula relies only on values in the same column. Not a requirement, but helpful because it can be used in the right-most column of your spreadsheet without modification.

Instead of placing the year into A2, you could choose to:

- have the year determined automatically using `=year(today())`, or
- referencing another cell in your spreadsheet.

### Edit: Localization Issues with Google Spreadsheet Dates

The above solution works - but not in Italy, and perhaps not in other locales. Both the `Date()` and `EDate()` functions result in "parse errors" in Google Spreadsheets for users with Locale == Italia.

To get around that, the custom function below converts a given date value into a string in the proper format for the `date` operator in `QUERY`. See [this blog entry](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions) for more information about custom functions. All you need to do is select "Script Editor..." from the "Tools" menu, paste this block of code into the editor workspace, and save it. You can name the script anything you like.

```
/**
 * Return the given date as a string formatted as 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
 */
function date2string(dateval) {
    var d = new Date(dateval);
    var dateArr = [];
    dateArr[0]=d.getFullYear();
    dateArr[1]=d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    dateArr[2]=d.getDate();
    return dateArr.join('-');  
}
```

With the script in place, you have a new function `date2string()` that you can use in your spreadsheet. The updated formula for cell C3 is:

```
=INDEX(query('Scheda Intervento'!$C$2:$K$13;"select sum (K) where (F >= date '" & date2string(C$2) & "' and F < date '" & date2string(D$2) & "' and C = '" & $A3 &"')");2;1)
```

### Problem with INDEX()

There's another problem with this formula, and it's with the `INDEX()` function. That function expects an array as input, along with indices to index an item in the array. That works well when `QUERY()` finds data that meets the criteria in the query string. In that case, the return from `QUERY('Scheda Intervento'!$C$2:$K$13;"select...` is something like this 2-row array:

```
Sum
54
```

In that case, `INDEX([["Sum"],[54]];2;1)` results in `54`, picked from row 2 col 1 of the array.

But if we have no matching data, there is no row 2, and we have a `#REF` error. We can avoid that by simply using `SUM()` to add the numeric values of the array. When there is no number, that will result in `0` - perfect.

Here's the resulting formula for cell C3:

```
    =SUM(query('Scheda Intervento'!$C$2:$K$13;"select sum (K) where (F >= date '" & date2string(C$2) & "' and F < date '" & date2string(D$2) & "' and C = '" & $A3 &"')"))
```

Comment: great!! but the formula doesn't work  ..maybe i have done a syntax error?? formula is in c3 in the sheet "riepilogo totale ore , date, compensi operatore" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtZwzv4EAc54dGRkcnlOS2JoMjZJQjktOGR4aENUX0E#gid=5

Comment: @user38384 There is a localization problem with the `TEXT()` and `EDATE()` functions. If I copy your spreadsheet contents to my own (EN-US) version, the functions work. In your (IT-IT) version, I get "parse error" for a simple function `=TEXT(c$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")`, although it works in mine. Similar for `EDATE()`. To get around that, I've written a custom function, and updated my answer. I can't find any help about how those functions should operate in Italian; can you?

Comment: I've reported these localization issues to Google. I'm sure they'll get right on them. :^/